# maven password encryption (settings-security.xml) not working using external binary through m2e

Tags: maven, maven-2

I am using eclipse indigo, with subclipse 1.8, and the latest version of m2eclipse. However, due to the fact that the embedded version of maven within m2e is broken when performing releases, I have configured eclipse to use my maven installation located at e:/maven-3.0.3.

Instead of storing my settings.xml file in C:\Users\Sam.m2 like I normally would, I am now storing my settings.xml file in e:\maven-3.0.3\conf, for uniformity purposes. Since I am not using the embedded version of maven, it makes sense to use only one settings file, located where my external binary is.

Here is the problem - I have created a master password and stored it in settings-security.xml and put it in my c:\users\sam.m2 directory, according to the format on the maven mini-guide. I have also duplicated it and stored it in my e:\maven-3.0.3\conf directory. The settings-security file exists in both places, before I run "mvn --encrypt-password" from the command line. So then I do "mvn --encrypt-password myrepopass" after my master password is created, and settings-security.xml is located in both places.

When I put plain-text passwords in settings.xml, everything works fine. When I encrypt them using the master I have specified, I get this error when trying to do something which checks out from scm (such as mvn release:prepare). Not sure why this isn't working.

```
[ERROR] svn: E170001: OPTIONS of 'https://secure.myrepo.com/svn/scoresecret/trunk /scs-global-parent': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected    Basic challenge (https://secure.myrepo.com)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your case, but in my practice encrypted passwords were used only to access Maven repositories and not SCM repositories. In what sections of `settings.xml` are you using your password?

Comment: Taking what you've written here and incorporating it into an answer. You're basically right

Comment: I hope you don't use m2eclipse with Indigo, cause for Indigo you should use m2e !

Comment: Can you give the snippet of the settings.xml and the appropriate scm area of your pom.xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason, the maven encryption mini-guide technique doesn't work with SCM servers - only artifact repositories. Not 100% sure why, but others have had the same issue.